# Simplest solution to addressing SSL certificates on internal applications

Tags: tls

I am having a discussion with a few coworkers about the best way we can handle SSL certificates within our organization. We have some internal applications that are not using any SSL certificates at all.

My thought is this:

- Create an offline, trusted, root CA in a VM
- Use this CA to issue certificates for our applications
- Use GPO to push the root CA onto all systems so it is trusted

Are there any drawbacks or pitfalls to this approach?

Comment: I take it by *tickets* you actually mean certificates?  If so, then yes, this is standard practice, used by many companies for internal applications/websites.

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Comment: Yup I meant certificates.  Brain = fried from dealing with a ticketing system this morning :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Since you mentioned GPO, it sounds like you have a Microsoft Active Directory.  Therefore, the easiest would be to leverage [Microsoft Active Directory Certificate Services (ADCS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448615.aspx).

Definitely want an offline root CA if you're supporting an enterprise environment.  This typically means deploying a two tier architecture.  Meaning there'll still be the offline Root CA but another server will be configured as the Issuing CA and will remain online.  [There's a great tutorial for setting up a two tier architecture here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831348.aspx).

FWIW, ADCS is fairly easy to setup and deploy.  The difficult part is fully understanding all the moving parts so it can be properly configured for your network.  Such items include how often the revocation lists are updated and setting up the appropriate level of overlap, where will the revocation lists and certificates get published, are there any legacy applications/clients that need to be supported, etc.  Luckily Microsoft has been doing a great job creating documentation for ADCS.  There is a [Design Guide here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2901.public-key-infrastructure-design-guidance.aspx) as well as a [document for securing a Microsoft PKI here](http://blogs.microsoft.com/cybertrust/2014/06/11/new-guidance-for-securing-public-key-infrastructure/).

Using a GPO is the right approach for pushing out the certificate from your Root CA to domain joined systems.  Have a plan for non-domain joined systems too such as alternative platforms (Apple, *nix).  This goes back to my prior comment about planning where the certificates will be served along with the revocation lists.  AD is great, but also consider a more accessible web server.

All of this will allow you to issue SSL certificates (and many more!) that will be trusted by internal clients or more specifically anyone that trusts your Root CA.

Comment: Thanks!  This provided very helpful information.  My goal is to create a simple request form that allows app owners to request certs for their apps that are valid from the enterprise perspective.  Slowly trying to introduce a secure culture :)

Comment: We do have many, many Unix systems, so would you recommend avoiding ADCS?

Comment: No, not avoid ADCS. It just isn't as streamlined for non-domain joined systems since a GPO can't be used. If there are many Unix systems, I'm guessing there is something in place to manage them (puppet, chef, cfengine) so use that method for distributing the trusted root cert.

Comment: ADCS will setup a webapp during installation allowing authorized users to access it and request certificates. Create a security group for all users requesting an SSL cert and add it to the certificate template (Web Server SSL? or create your own) with the necessary level of access.